# Remove default JFrame icon

Tags: java, swing, icons, jframe

In my JFrame i have the default coffee icon. I want to remove it. But when i do setIconImage(null) it does't work. Can anyone tell me the solution as to how to completely remove the icon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create icon that consists of one pixel (better transparent) and use it. If you need such icon contact me. I will send you.

Comment: A transparent 1px icon can be generated in a few lines of code.

Answer (score 25):

It's always good to keep a copy of the [Java source code](http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/) around.  The code for java.awt.Window (a superclass of JFrame) has the following code for `setIconImage`:

```
public void setIconImage(Image image)
{
  ArrayList<Image> imageList = new ArrayList<Image>();
  if (image != null)
  {
    imageList.add(image);
  }
  setIconImages(imageList);
}
```

You can see that passing in a null image is the same as doing nothing so you'll have to pass in an image to get rid of the coffee cup.  As others have suggested using a 1 x 1 transparent icon is your best bet.  Here is some code to create the icon:

```
Image icon = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE);
myFrame.setIconImage(icon);
```

Comment: I would complete the last line this way: `myFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(icon));`

Answer (score 2):

You can set the image icon to a transparent image which will remove the coffee cup. I don't believe it is possible to get rid of the default icon otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use gimp or photoshop or even paint and create a 1x1px, transparent image, export it (.png or .jpg, doesnt matter?). 
Then apply it:

```
ImageIcon frameIcon = new ImageIcon("files\yourfile.png");
frame.setIconImage(frameIcon.getImage());
```

Should be fine.